# Trouble getting the top and bottom of an imageView

Tags: android, size, screen

I have a simple drawing app where I have a picture of a letter in the back filling an ImageView set to 45% of the screen's height. I have a JSON file that stores points along the letter. I'm trying to display those points on top of the picture of the letter.

Those points' coordinates range between y = -440 and y = 200. In order to properly display the points I need the top and the height of the imageView containing the letter to map the points onto the screen. I have to map the points to the proper points in runtime because with different screen sizes need different scale to display the points properly.

This is what it should look like (this is with a phone specific correction factor):

[image]

This is what it actually looks like:

[image]

I render the drawing via a Canvas that I paint the points onto. I'm pretty sure the problem lies in how I'm getting the top of the ImageView.

Here's what I've tried:

```
    //1
    float y = view.getTop();
    //2
    final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
    iv.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
    float y = screenPos[1];
    //3
    float offset = iv.getTop() - screenPos[1];
    float y = iv.getTop() + offset;
```

Is there something I'm supposed to be doing that I'm not? Is there a better way the relative returns of getTop()? Help.

Comment: view.getTop() is the right way to go but it returns the position relative to the direct parent . Maybe you need to check if there is another parent for your view and this messes up how the dots are drawn

Comment: Isn't that what using getLocationOnScreen is supposed to get around?

Comment: yes,it is did you try  the step 2 on its own?   final int[] screenPos = new int[2];
    iv.getLocationOnScreen(screenPos);
    float y = screenPos[1]; .......if you did I wanna suggest just one other solution I can think of

Comment: Yeah it didn't work. It's still bad on most screens and really bad on large screens.

Comment: okey I will post an answer because it the only thing else I can suggest

Answer (score 1):

It will give you the position relative to the screen

```
Rect rect = new Rect();

view.getGlobalVisibleRect(rect);

float top = rect.top;

//there is also rect.bottom, rect.width, rect.height etc.
```

Comment: It's still not working. So the canvas is stored in a View subclass (which is positioned at 0,0). When I calculate the top and the bottom is in onSizeChanged(). Could the problem be there (maybe the imageView isn't fully processed?)?

Comment: Really weird cause this code works best for me( It could be that the ImageView is not fully processed so you can try and move your code to the onStart() when all the views are already drawn to cancel out this possibility

Comment: Okay, I think I've figured it out almost. I think its pixel density issue. I had the canvas draw out the rect and it matched. I can make it work for phones that have the same density but not when the screen's density is different. I don't know how to work with different densities though...

Comment: are you using dp? I believe you do but still. dp is density pixels . It is designed to prevent the situation you have. You don;t actually need to work with different density if you use dp it gets adjust automatically https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities?hl=en

Comment: As in, I think its a problem with the mapping function. So when I have phones with low dp(i?), the dots are too high. With higher than 420 dp(i), the dots are too low. And any phone with 420 dpi is just right.

Comment: Oh yeah, it's working now. I applied a correction factor thats a function of the dpi, and it's working fine now

Comment: Great to hear that! Consider posting your solution as an answer so people can get help when they face similar problems!

Comment: @JeanValjean Can you please post the solution? I am facing the similar issue in my app.